# ASP.NET MVC Outputcache "thread safe"

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, multithreading, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using the attribute `[OutputCache(Duration=XXX)]` (and also the donut variant `[DonutOutputCache(Duration=XXX)]`).

However I noticed (confirmed by [ASP.NET (MVC) Outputcache and concurrent requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2162433/asp-net-mvc-outputcache-and-concurrent-requests)) this is not thread safe: when the cache is re-generated, if the controller method is slow enough (and it's usually the case, this is why you cache it ^^), multiple "identical" requests can enter the action an perform the operations, instead of having only 1 request processed, blocking the other requests and serving them from the cache.

Is there any way to easily make a blocking/thread safe `OutputCache` attribute? Same question for `DonutOutputCache`? Like `[BlockingOutputCache(SameParameters)]` and `[BlockingDonutOutputCache(SameParameters)]`

Note: cached actions are regular actions, returning `View(model)`, heavy work is done in the action and in the view (the view can do something very simple like @Model.GetPrice() which translates to heavy lifting in the backend).

Thanks!

Edit: another way could be to create a `[BlockingAction(BlockingParameters)]` attribute that would block subsequent requests to this action when not served from the cache.

Comment: The link that you already did post solves your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the VaryByCustom. In Global.asax override the GetVaryByCustomString method. Then create unique cache key, and use double checked locking on your cache storage. It's sync way. I may guess that exists async way when you begin cache resolving and then end cache resolving.

Comment: This is actually pretty smart and doesn't requires lot of changes! I'll try to figure out the details (I might create a special attribute, I don't exactly now what I'm gonna do yet) and keep this question up to date. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: I +'d it, but it's too generic to be the "accepted" answer, sorry.